How to focus an input dynamically
When a user presses a button, an input is displayed, I simply want to focus the input at that time. Something like this:
<script>
    let edit = false;
    let focusInput = {};
    const toggleEdit = ()=>{
        edit = true;
        focusInput.focus();
    }
</script>

<button on:click={toggleEdit}>Edit</button>
{#if edit}
    <input type="text" bind:this={focusInput}>
{/if}

The problem is that focusInput is undefined. I know that you are supposed to use onMount() for this, but it is user input, the component has already long been mounted by the time the button is pressed. So it doesn't make sense that focusInput is still undefined.
Also, I can't call a function in the HTML that is defined in onMount(). How can I get access to a DOM element during user input?
It honestly doesn't make sense, it is like Svelte is blocking me from ever having access to DOM elements.
To be clear, I am asking how to focus an already existing DOM element. This: How to focus on newly added inputs in Svelte?, does not answer the question at all.

It does answer the question in multiple ways. You have not shown how this is in any way not answered. Elements in #if do not exist until the condition is true and the DOM updated.

No, it does not answer it. Read the question and try to use your brain for once. The actual question has nothing to do with focus. It is about accessing the DOM element.

It does not matter if you focus or not. The linked questions show various approaches of interacting with the element instance, you just misunderstood how Svelte works and assumed that the element is there when it isn't.
